# Guidelines for determining the maximum frequency to process an SSAS cube?

Tags: ssas, cube

We have an Analysis Services cube that needs to be as real-time as possible.  It's a relatively small cube that currently takes a couple of seconds to process.

Are there any guidelines for this?  I'm curious what other folks are doing.

Also, what would be the impact of processing the cube too frequently?  Would the main concern be the load on the SSAS server and the source DB?  In our case it would be fairly nominal.  How would SSAS clients be affected?  Current SSAS consumers are Excel, PerformancePoint, and Sharepoint/Excel Services.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the first issue you'd have to consider is how much is this cube going to grow over time? If it is constantly updated and processed that couple seconds could quickly turn into 20 minutes.

For example, we currently have a cube that has 20 million rows (probably more now hehe) with financial data related to hospital billing and charges that takes about 20 mins to process and we do it once a day in the morning. Depending on the time of the year we sometimes do process during the day again but there have been no complaints as long as we notify people we are doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a real-time (ROLAP) partition to store the current day's data? This way, you get the performance of MOLAP for all your data prior to the current day, which you can process nightly, but have ROLAP's low latency for the data collected since the last cube process.

If your cube is small enough, you could even stretch that to be the current week's data, or more.

As far as the disadvantages of processing frequently, check out the below article, which says: "If the processing job succeeds, an exclusive lock is put on the object when changes are being committed, which means the object is temporarily unavailable for query or processing. During the commit phase of the transaction, queries can still be sent to the object, but they will be queued until the commit is completed."
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174860.aspx

So your users will see an impact in query performance.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have to 'put it out there' and track how it performs.

Once you can see how people are using the cube, you can determine if constant reprocessing is really necessary and if it is, you may have to optimise how this occurs.

Spcifically using "usage based optimisation" as described here:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3575751/Usage-Based-Optimization-in-Analysis-Services-2005.htm